# CodeIgniter: Traer datos de la base de datos una ves seleccionado un option

Tags: php, bootstrap, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente SELECT:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="empleado">Selecciona un empleado</label>
         <select onchange="abrirModal($(this).val());" id="select_id" class="form-control">
           <option value="" >Seleccionar...</option>
           <?php foreach ($empleados as $e): ?>
              <option data-toggle="modal" value="<?php echo $e->legajo; ?>"> <?php echo $e->nombre;?> - <?php echo $e->apellido;?> </option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
          </select>
 </div>
```

En la cual, cuando se selecciona una opcion, se abre un modal. Paso por parametro a ese modal el LEGAJO de un usuario, pero necesitaria tambien ejecutar una funcion del Controller que me trae los meses disponibles de ese usuario.

Éste es el modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form class="form-signin text-center border brd-naranja pt-2" role="form" name="frmDescargaReciboSueldo" id="frmDescargaReciboSueldo" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>rrhh/recibosueldo/descargar">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <label for="idInput">Legajo del empleado: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="legajo" id="idInput" value="" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <label for="mes" style="display:inline;" class="control-label text-right"><?=lang('etiqueta_mes_recibo_sueldo')?></label>
                    <select name="mes" class="form-control colorNaranja" style="display:inline; width:25%">
                      <?php foreach ($mesesConRecibos as $meses) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo substr($meses['Key'],0,6); ?>"><?php echo substr($meses['Det'],-7); ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Descargar</button>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

El select, no tengo ninguna informacion, ya que no se como ejecutar una funcion del controlador.

y este es el script para abrir el modal:

```
<script>
function abrirModal(select_id){
$("#idInput").val(select_id);//asigna data a modal por id
$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

con AJAX pienso en un:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: base_url + "rrhh/recibosueldo/mesesconRecibosEmpleados/" + select_id, //recordar sin el .php
          data: select_id,
          success: function(data)
          {
            $('#resp').html(data);
            console.log(data);
          }
      });
```

pero como haria para no refrescar la pagina, sino se me cierra el modal.

EDIT: pude obtener la data, pero como podria llenar al SELECT con esa data???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has estudiado algo de ajax?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Puede ser

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ahi edite la publicacion

Comment: no entiendo esta pregunta:  llenar al SELECT con esa data?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Los datos que traigo con AJAX, Deberian ir en el select.

Comment: y si usas select2: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: Podrias recorrer la data con un forEach y hacer un append al select. Seria algo así:  

`
data.forEach((fila)=>{
  $("#select_id").append(`<option value="${fila.el_dato}">${fila.el_dato} </option>`)
})
`